# Can gorm.DB automatically resolve foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database, go, orm, go-gorm

I'm trying to use https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm to automatically map foreign keys for me but somehow either I'm doing it wrong or the library cannot do it and I'm in the wrong.

I have the following `struct`s:

```golang
type Currency struct {
  ID           uint64 `gorm:"primary_key"`
  CurrencyCode string `gorm:"size:3"`
}

type Rate struct {
  ID          uint64 `gorm:"primary_key"`
  CurrencyID  uint64
  Currency    Currency `gorm:"ForeignKey:CurrencyID"`
  Price       float64
}
```

and the following SQL tables (**edited so that currency_code is unique**)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `rates` (
  `id` serial PRIMARY KEY,
  `currency_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rate_currency`
    FOREIGN KEY (currency_id) REFERENCES currencies(id)
);

CREATE TABLE `currencies` (
  `id` serial PRIMARY KEY,
  `currency_code` char(3) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Now I thought that when I do something like this:

```golang
rate := Rate{
  Currency: Currency{
    CurrencyCode: "USD",
  },
  Price: 123,
}
db, _  := gorm.Open("mysql", ...)
db.Create(&rate)
```

then `"USD"` would get automatically mapped to a `currency_id` but instead it inserts new `"USD"` entry in `currencies` table for every `db.Create(&rate)`

Am I doing it wrong or it's the library?

**EDIT**

I know that I can do it by querying the DB for currency ID

```golang
curr := db.Currency{}
db.Where("currency_code = ?", "USD").First(&curr)
// use curr with proper ID
```

but then:

- I have to make 2 DB calls
- I don't use `gorm`'s foreign key mapping feature (if there is one)

Comment: I'm not a gorm user but how would you expect this to work? You don't provide a foreign key value when inserting, you only provide the currency code which is not the foreign key and is not even unique, how is the orm supposed to know your thoughts?

Comment: @mkopriva I'd imagine that there's at least one way of doing that by using a subquery with WHERE currency_code = "USD".

Comment: Given your table schema `WHERE currency_code = "USD"` may return multiple rows... regardless of that, without making the currency code the actual foreign key the orm would have to make assumptions based on whatever to meet your expectations, those expectations would most certainly be at odds with the expectations of the majority of gorm's users. It seems logical to me that the orm creates a new record if no fkey is provided, and links to an existing record if one is provided, don't you think?

Comment: @mkopriva how about something like: `INSERT INTO rates (currency_id, price) VALUES
    ((SELECT id FROM currencies WHERE currency_code = "USD"), 123.12);`

Comment: Seems ok to me if you write that sql yourself as opposed to rely on an orm to do it for you. But make sure currency_code is unique.

Answer (score 1):

In their [documentation](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#associations) it states:

> By default when creating/updating a record, GORM will save its associations, if the association has primary key, GORM will call Update to save it, otherwise it will be created.

So when you want to map to a certain entry you must correlate it with the ID, otherwise it will create a new record.

In your case you could use the `currency_code` as the **PRIMARY KEY** for `Currency` (use fixed number of chars to make it faster, not varchar, like `sql:"type:char(3);unique"`).

This would eliminate the need of a search by ID anymore, it would just find "USD" as primary key and use it => no more multiple records per currency. Also if there is a currency that it does not have, it will create it in the `Currency` table.

Also you can eliminate the `gorm:"ForeignKey:CurrencyID"` struct tag and let GORM create it's own tables with [AutoMigrate](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/database.html#migration), and would create the tables with the appropriate FK:

```
db := gorm.Open("mysql", ...)
db.Set("gorm:table_options", "ENGINE=InnoDB")
db.Set("gorm:table_options", "collation_connection=utf8_general_ci")
// Migrate the schema
db.AutoMigrate(&models.Currency{})
db.AutoMigrate(&models.Rate{})
```

Comment: `use fixed number of chars to make it faster, not varchar`- I'm already using that right? `char(3)` in DB schema and `CurrencyCode string 'gorm:"size:3"'` in go code.

Comment: yeah right, I did not notice that, but it will still make it a varchar of length 3.

Comment: And I don't understand how using `currency_code` as PRIMARY KEY would help me here

Comment: Because you do not have to search by ID anymore, it would just find "USD" as primary key and use it => no more multiple records per currency.

Answer (score 1):

In recently released GORM 2.0, foreign keys get added to your database automatically provided your GORM tags are correct. You can say AutoMigrate got smarter.

Just upgrade and use the new imports

```
go get gorm.io/gorm

import (
  "gorm.io/gorm"
  "gorm.io/driver/sqlite" //or whatever driver
)
```

PS: There are some breaking changes with the new version, kindly check the official relase note for more info https://gorm.io/docs/v2_release_note.html